# row height increase after few row in mpdf

Tags: php, mpdf

I am using mpdf. After a few loops, the height of the table row increases. I couldn't figure out why. Can anyone help me with this?[image]

And it continues like point 13 until the second loop .

Here is the code

```
                <tbody>                
              <?php $i=1; foreach ($veriable as $value) { $++; ?>
              <tr>
                <th class="no-top no-bottom"></th>
                <td><?= $i; ?>.</td>
                <td><?= $value->a; ?></td>
                <td><?= $value->b; ?></td>
                <td><?= $value->c; ?></td>
                <td><?= std_date($value->d); ?></td>
                <td><?= $value->e; ?></td>
                <td><?= $value->f; ?></td>
                <td><?= $value->g; ?></td>
                <td><?= $value->h; ?></td>
                <td><?= $value->i; ?></td>
              </tr>
              <?php } ?>
```

Comment: It seems strange indeed... Did you try removing the empty `th` to test?

Comment: Other thing, if you echo the result in browser, it also comes out like that?

Comment: Yes, I have tried both of them. But nothing change.

Comment: But if you echo the result in html, the height keeps increasing? If so, then you can use Developer Console to check what can be causing it.

Comment: Though the error didn't show up in the developer console.  It was caused by a PHP variable. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Though the error didn't show up in the developer console. It was caused by a PHP variable. And I was able to fix it by checking all the variables.